# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors Computation in Intel Math Kernel

Tags: eigenvector, eigenvalue, intel-mkl

Does any know what is the algorithm used for eigenvalues and eigenvectors computation in Intel Math Kernel library? [From the link](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/mkl/mkl_indepth.pdf) I can find is that it seems to use [pdsyev algorithm](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/html/src/pdsyev.f), which uses QR algorithm, that would [deteriorate in the face of large matrix](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node119.html).

If this were true, then the mkl isn't a suitable library for computing large scale eigenvalue problem.

What do you think? Or is it that I misunderstand the above text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge the MKL represents a "normal" Lapack packaged with an optimized Blas. Maybe with some small extras here and there. However, the Lapack contains only O(N^3)-scaling algorithms for the computation of eigenvalues and -vectors. For large-scale problems -- if only a limited number of eigenvalues is required -- other libraries like e.g. [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) can perform much better.